# How to add style to the matching string of text?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, css

I have got the list of elements like this:

```
<p style="text-align: center;">
<b>List textlink</b>
<a class="link link--external has-favicon" href="#abc.com/abc" target="_blank" rel="noopener">ANONFILE</a> - 
<a class="link link--external has-favicon" href="#abc.com/xyz" target="_blank" rel="noopener">GOFILE</a> - 
<a class="link link--external has-favicon" href="#abc.com/123" target="_blank" rel="noopener">MEGA</a>
</p>
```

Textlink is: ANONFILE, GOFILE, MEGA

With Javascript/JQuery/CSS, Is there anyway I can check textlink and could simply only change the element's CSS if the inner Textlink equals:

- IF textlink equal "ANONFILE" style css

```
font-size: 9px;
    color: red;
    letter-spacing: 0.5px;
```

- IF textlink equal "GOFILE" style css

```
font-size: 10px;
    color: yellow;
    letter-spacing: 0.6px;
```

- IF textlink equal "MEGA" style css

```
font-size: 11px;
    color: green;
    letter-spacing: 0.7px;
```

The only way I know to do this is to get all of the links and loop through them checking to see if the textlink contains the string I am searching for.

Is there a better way to do this without change original code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write the classes in CSS, then add the `.textContent`s as a class, like this:

```js
for (el of document.querySelectorAll('.link')) {
  el.classList.add(el.textContent.replaceAll(' ', ''));
}
```

```css
.ANONFILE {
  font-size: 9px;
  color: red;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
}

.GOFILE {
  font-size: 10px;
  color: yellow;
  letter-spacing: 0.6px;
}

.MEGA {
  font-size: 11px;
  color: green;
  letter-spacing: 0.7px;
}

.GOOGLEDRIVE {
  font-size: 15px;
  color: blue;
  letter-spacing: 1.1px;
}
```

```html
<p style="text-align: center;">
  <b>List textlink</b>
  <a class="link link--external has-favicon" href="#abc.com/abc" target="_blank" rel="noopener">ANONFILE</a> -
  <a class="link link--external has-favicon" href="#abc.com/xyz" target="_blank" rel="noopener">GOFILE</a> -
  <a class="link link--external has-favicon" href="#abc.com/123" target="_blank" rel="noopener">MEGA</a>
  <a class="link link--external has-favicon" href="#abc.com/123" target="_blank" rel="noopener">GOOGLE DRIVE</a>
</p>
```

Comment: can you tell me how to style if text link have 2 word like GOOGLE DRIVE?

Comment: @Yesyeahvh I've updated my answer to address that. Just add a class name without the space, then have the JS remove the from before it adds the class name. See my edit.

Answer (score 1):

Looping through as you suggested would work, but if you're able to add each link's text to a [`data-*` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*) in your HTML in advance like so:

```html
<p style="text-align: center;">
<b>List textlink</b>
<a data-text="ANONFILE" class="link link--external has-favicon" href="#abc.com/abc" target="_blank" rel="noopener">ANONFILE</a> - 
<a data-text="GOFILE" class="link link--external has-favicon" href="#abc.com/xyz" target="_blank" rel="noopener">GOFILE</a> - 
<a data-text="MEGA" class="link link--external has-favicon" href="#abc.com/123" target="_blank" rel="noopener">MEGA</a>
</p>
```

Then you could simply target the links in CSS using [attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors):

```css
.link[data-text="ANONFILE"] {
  font-size: 9px;
  color: red;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
}

.link[data-text="GOFILE"] {
  font-size: 10px;
  color: yellow;
  letter-spacing: 0.6px;
}

.link[data-text="ANONFILE"] {
  font-size: 11px;
  color: green;
  letter-spacing: 0.7px;
}
```

Which seems a bit simpler, and might be more performant. Note that the `data-*` attribute is needed because [CSS does not provide a way to target elements based on their text content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520429/is-there-a-css-selector-for-elements-containing-certain-text).

Comment: good idea but the problem is there are hundreds of posts like this so i can't edit it in html

Comment: @Yesyeahvh it is possible to make use of the href attribute and `*=` at the selector for a [`contains`](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors/#overview) search. For example: `.link[href*="drive.google.com"] { }` -- With this you don't have to modify the classes of the elements, which might be a problem with the accepted answer. When a new element is added dynamically, they won't have the CSS classes applied and you have to execute the JS part again.